# How to get glossary terms to properly typeset subscripts/superscripts?

Tags: glossaries, subscripts, superscripts

I have just begun using the `glossaries` package. I have created a glossary entry for the coproduct symbol as disjoint union:

```
\newglossaryentry{coprod}
{
    name = {\ensuremath{\coprod}},
    description = {The coproduct in the category of sets, i.e., the disjoint union},
    sort = coprod,
    symbol = {\ensuremath{\coprod}}
}
```

Where I put either `\gls{coprod}` or `\glssymbol{coprod}` in the body of my document, it prints the coproduct symbol correctly, but it doesn't format subscripts and superscripts (e.g. `\gls{coprod}_1^r`) as it would for the `\coprod` symbol in math mode (i.e. above and below). Instead, they're to the right, and too close together. How can I fix this?

**Addendum:** An example of the call to `\gls{coprod}` in my code looks like:

```
\[
[n] = \gls{coprod}_1^r \lambda_i
\]
```

Comment: Are you in math mode issuing your `\gls`? If not that's your problem, but since it is not clear what your context is please provide a MWE.

Comment: Yes the `\gls` is in math mode. I will try Elad Den's displaystyle idea.

Comment: @TeXnician - I would have tried what Elad Den put in his answer as a MWE, but actually it comes out fine for me too. My issue is happening in a large project (a PhD thesis), using a lot of different packages. I assume at this point that the issue has to do with interaction among the parts. If it is not already a known bug, then I doubt I will be able to isolate the issue without more work than it is worth to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and when researching found this answer immediately, yet it did not solve my problem.

What did, was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320507/position-of-powers-subscripts-when-using-symbols-symbolslist-via-glossaries) answer, also found on tex exchange.

It seems to be necessary to pass the superscripts or subscript as optional argument to the `\gls{}` call in the form of `\gls{<name>}[_{xx}^{yy}]`. Below is an example of this in action:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{sym}{
    name = {\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}},
    description = {Real numbers}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

$\gls{sym}[^3_x]$ in a text.
\begin{align}
    \gls{sym}[_t^{2\times3}]
\end{align}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: This is what the above code looks like compiled.]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the problem is. Trying to simulate it I was unable to recreate it.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{coprod}
{
    name = {\ensuremath{\coprod}},
    description = {The coproduct in the category of sets, i.e., the disjoint union},
    sort = coprod,
    symbol = {\ensuremath{\coprod}}
    }

\begin{document}
    coprod in a paragraph $\coprod_{1}^{2}$
    \[
        \coprod_{1}^{2}
    \]

    gls in paragraph $\gls{coprod}_{1}^{2}$
    \[
        \gls{coprod}_{1}^{2}
    \]

\end{document}
```

It sounds like you are not in display style, so either you using `\gls` in a `$$` environment, in which case the super and subscript SHOULD be on the side, or there's some other problem. In any case, try defining `name = {\ensuremath{\displaystyle\coprod}},`

Comment: Thanks (+1). I tried adding the `\displaystyle` but it didn't help. If I replace the `\gls{coprod}` in the body of my document with `\coprod`, it prints as I want it to. Could `glossaries` be interacting badly with some other package?

Comment: maybe... hard to tell, that's why a MWE is needed... If I had to guess I'd bet on the `documentclass` rather than a package, are you using some sort of thesis `documentclass` ?

Comment: I'm using `\documentclass{report}`

Comment: When I try your code with `\documentclass{report}` instead of `{article}` it still looks fine. I think that figuring out a MWE is going to take far more work than it's worth to me. I will either just have to live with the bad formatting, figure out a manual workaround, or else take `\coprod` out of the glossary. I posted the question hoping it was a known bug.

Comment: In the `\[ \]` environment, I can get around the need to fix this using `\underset` and `\overset`. In the `$$` environment, it's still a problem because although the subscript/superscript are to the right like they should be, they're further from the `\coprod` symbol than they should be, and too close together.